# Change SurfaceView Image Depending On Thumbnail

Tags: android

So far I have an `Activity` where there are a selection of thumbnails, once a thumbnail is clicked it opens up the `Camera Activity` with the `SurfaceView` which is being set in the XML below:

I need a way to be able to change the `SurafceView` depending on which thumbail was choosen in the previous `Activity` I have the thumbnails set up as `buttons`. I have given each button the same ID as the image name it should use on the `SurfaceView` so is there a way to take the button `ID` and change the `RelativeLayout` background below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/overlay"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/takepicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="10px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/capture" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl 
        = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);
```

Comment: Are u starting a new Activity or just set the new layout?

Comment: Matt, you've forgotten to add Camera Activity xml layout. Besides it isn't very clear what you're trying to do with the buttons ids.

Answer (score 1):

When starting up the Camera activity, put the ID of the background you want into the intent's extras bundle like so:

```
intent.putExtra("backgroundId", backgroundId);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the second activity you retrieve the background ID from your intent and assign it to the background of the root view:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
     ...
     int backgroundId = getIntent().getIntExtra("backgroundId", 0);
     viewControl.setBackgroundResouce(backgroundId);
     ...
}
```